# Llamaindex cannot persist index to Chroma DB and load later

Tags: python, llama-index, chromadb

I am creating 2 apps using `Llamaindex`. One allows me to create and store indexes in `Chroma DB` and other allows me to later load from this storage and query.

Here is my code to load and persist data to ChromaDB:

```
import chromadb
from chromadb.config import Settings
chroma_client = chromadb.Client(Settings(
    chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet",
    persist_directory=".chroma/" # Optional, defaults to .chromadb/ in the current directory
))
chroma_collection = chroma_client.get_or_create_collection("quickstart")

def chromaindex():
    
    
    UnstructuredReader = download_loader("UnstructuredReader")
    loader = UnstructuredReader()
    documents = loader.load_data(file= Path())

    # create chroma vector store
    vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, storage_context=storage_context)

    index.storage_context.persist(vector_store_fname = 'demo')
```

Here is my code to later load the storage context and query:

```
import chromadb
from chromadb.config import Settings
chroma_client = chromadb.Client(Settings(
    chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet",
    persist_directory=".chroma/" # Optional, defaults to .chromadb/ in the current directory
))
chroma_collection = chroma_client.get_collection("quickstart")

def chroma_ans(question):
    
    vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
    sc = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
    
    index2 = load_index_from_storage(sc)
    query_engine = index2.as_query_engine()
    response = query_engine.query("What did the author do growing up?")
    return response
```

When I run the 2nd code to query, I get `ValueError: No index in storage context, check if you specified the right persist_dir.`. I am not sure where I am making the mistake. ALl I want to do is in first app, create `storage context` and `index` and store then using `Chroma DB` and in second app load them again to query.

My `llamindex` version is `0.6.9`

Comment: Do you specifically need `chromadb` for your operation ? If not, you can directly save and load it from disk using the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved updating chromadb to the latest 0.4...

TO SAVE TO THE DISK

```
chroma_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./dist/vdb", settings=Settings(
    anonymized_telemetry=False
))

chroma_collection = chroma_client.get_or_create_collection("quickstart")

vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store ) # <- here don't specify persist_dir

cur_index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(data, storage_context=storage_context, service_context=service_context)

# Here you save to the path you want
cur_index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir="./dist/vdb/liama")
```

TO LOAD FROM DISK

```
chroma_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./dist/vdb", settings=Settings(
    anonymized_telemetry=False
))

chroma_collection = chroma_client.get_or_create_collection("quickstart")

vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store, , persist_dir="./dist/vdb/liama" ) # <- here you DO specify persist_dir

# Now you can load the index
cur_index = GPTVectorStoreIndex([], storage_context=storage_context, service_context=service_context)
```